# Big Sur menu bar changes color from black to white when switching virtual desktops – possible to pin it to a single color?

Tags: big-sur, desktop, menu-bar, bug, color

So my menu bar changes its color when I switch virtual desktops. On desktop 1, I have black text on a white menu bar. On Desktop 2, it is white text on white menu bar. On desktop 3 and beyond, it is white text on a dark menu bar:

[image]

The menu bar on Desktop 2 is mostly unreadable. I think this is a bug, since changing the wallpaper temporarily solves the problem (all virtual desktops appear using a menu bar style consistent with virtual desktop 1) but the problem returns after a short time. I also tried switching "Allow wallpaper tinting in windows" off, however, this didn't fix the problem. Is that a known bug? Does Apple have some sort of issue tracker?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. https://superuser.com/questions/1628345/macos-menu-bar-changes-color-from-black-to-white-when-switching-virtual-desktops

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't know about the migration feature, will remember that for the future!